# Why is function being called without clicking on button?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to move the smaller block 'onclick' of the button in html. But either it is not calling that function or may be it is calling it even before the button is clicked. How to find out and solve to get the required response?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var pos = 0;
//getting box element
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var time = setInterval(move, 10);
document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = move(){
    if(pos >= 150){
        clearInterval(time);
    } else{
        pos += 1;
        box.style.left = pos+"px";
    }
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1><p id="p1" style="color:#dd3333">Sample Game</p></h1>
<p id="p2" styel="color:#b5b5b5">Click on the button below</p>
<style>
#container{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:green;
position:relative;
}
#box{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:red;
position:absolute;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
<div id="box"></div>
</div>
<br></br>
<button id="btn1">Click Me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.onclick = move()` You know what is the diffrence between function call and function reference?

Comment: Doesn't `var time = setInterval(move, 10);` call the function as-well?

Comment: @Teemu I am not sure.

Comment: You're almost there, only that you've forgotten `function` keyword, + Roko's answer shows the way you should do it.

Comment: @AlonEitan even if I comment out 'var time = setInterval(...' it doesn't work.

Comment: So I guess, it will be, var time = setInterval(move, 10);
document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function move(){
 if(pos >= 150){
  clearInterval(time);
 } else{
  pos += 1;
  box.style.left = pos+"px";
 }
};

Comment: Doesn't work... I tested with an alert, if function was being called on click event: `//var time = setInterval(move, 10);
document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = move();

function move(){
 /*if(pos >= 150){
  clearInterval(time);
 } else{
  pos += 1;
  box.style.left = pos+"px";
 }*/
 alert("New");
}`

Comment: @SanjeevKumarPandey: `...onclick = move();` is wrong. Some beginner tutorials and a linter are probably in order so that you won't have to keep guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're directly calling a function `move`. Instead:

```
function move(){
    if(pos >= 150){
        clearInterval(time);
    } else{
        pos += 1;
        box.style.left = pos+"px";
    }
}


document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", move);
```

Additionally, since you don't use any DOM ready handler to make sure the document is ready and parsed by JS - place your `<script>` file before the closing `</body>` tag. or do a quick google how to incorporate such a function that will tell you JS can safely operate over DOM elements. (jQuery here, for example is your friend)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <style>
    #container {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: green;
      position: relative;
    }
    #box {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background: red;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="box"></div>
  </div>

  <button id="btn1">Click Me</button>

  <script>
    var pos = 0;
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
    var time = null;


    function move() {
      if (pos >= 150) {
        clearInterval(time);
      } else {
        pos += 1;
        box.style.left = pos + "px";
      }
    }

    document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
      time = setInterval(move, 10);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This answer, plus you're trying to get the element by ID when the JS doesn't know it exists yet (it can't see anything from the <head> about what's in the <body> how you have it now). Put your JS under your HTML in the body to fix this.

Comment: @JustinMcCraw exactly. You have eagle eyes

Comment: @JustinMcCraw - good addition
@SanjeevKumarPandey it is also good practice to keep your css and javascript in separate files and reference css in `<head>` with `<link>` tag and Javascript with `<script>` tag, preferably just before `</body> closing tag. It ensures that the DOM is loaded, when your javascript runs.

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan and @TomaszBubala!

Comment: Finally Working now after using Roko's and objectively C's suggestions!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you do not need to reuse the function.

```
   document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function()
   {
       alert('you clicked me');
   }
```

Comment: This will still fail. They need the function for more than one purpose.

Comment: That is correct. If he needs to use the function again, he needs to bring the function out like Roko mentioned. If he does not need to re-use the function he can just use this.

Comment: `var time = setInterval(move, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<h1><p id="p1" style="color:#dd3333">Sample Game</p></h1>
<p id="p2" styel="color:#b5b5b5">Click on the button below</p>
<style>
#container{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:green;
position:relative;
}
#box{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:red;
position:absolute;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
<div id="box"></div>
</div>
<br></br>
<button id="btn1">Click Me</button>
<script>

function move(){
if(pos >= 150){
    clearInterval(time);
} else{
    pos += 1;
    box.style.left = pos+"px";
}
}


document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", move);
var pos = 0;
//getting box element
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var time = setInterval(move, 10);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should add an explanation with your answer.